# Galaxy S2, 3 year old. Battery went from 55% to 13% in 5 minutes, then phone started restarting

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, battery

this morning going to work I had my battery at 55% was listening to music and chatting in skype. All of the sudden skype started lagging really hard and then phone restarted. When it turned back on, the battery had went down to 13% and phone restarted quite a few times ever since

what could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was the battery life decrease sudden, or has it been getting noticeably worse recently? If so, might be time to get a new battery for your device. Regarding the restart, are there any apps that you've installed recently that might have a bug or something leading to restarts? When a phone reaches that age, I would personally root it and flash something like CM or Slimbean, to get some solid battery life back out of the device (I've personally flashed ChameleonOS on my S2 to get the best of both customization and battery).

Comment: apart from that accident I havent had problems with the battery. I do not know how to root it, not to mention flashing it :) I uninstalled couple of apps afterwards (unique galaxy, isGenuine and a few similar apps) also I uninstalled the last build of my own app and I havent had this problem since yesterday

Comment: Would you be willing to do so, though (rooting)? If so, XDA-Developers is a good place to start. It's got a bunch of how-tos and ROMs for you to check out. If it's a sudden decrease, I'm honestly not quite sure whether to direct you to buying a new battery or rooting the device, as I don't want to be the person who makes you buy a battery and have the problem fixed :P http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2 
Has the battery life improved since yesterday? Or is the device still down in the dumps and crashing?

Comment: no the device is perfectly fine every since :) I might check out that link though

Answer (score 0):

I have Faced the Same issue on my device. It was 2 years or so when I started experiencing the Problem. the Battery was draining inside 3 hours, even when the phone was in Stand By,flight mode .

When i checked my battery status

```
 *#*#4636#*#
```

The battery Health was shown good.
I checked the Battery operating voltage during the same period and the discharge voltage using a Mulimeter. The was a bit higher than expected and operating range, meaning the Battery was short.
Under the circumstance, i changed my battery.

Inside 3 Months I experinced the same problem again. The issue was traced out to the Charger, which was sourcing by Battery with a Higher than expected voltage continously causing damage to the Battery.

Proper Solution, 
1. Change the Battery, It would have already been short by now.
2. Check the Charger, (I dont know to check, i approched a specialist for this), get it replaced if necessary.

Now my phone is about 3 year old with still awesome battery performance. Only,issue at present is Touch Wiz RAM Hog, which wats up 80% of my RAM even on first Booth and Wiping Cache memory and disabling PreBuilt apps which I dont Use.